# Basic counting queries

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, group-by

I have 2 tables `class` and `grade`.

This are sample rows in the `class` table:

```
C_NAME....C_TIME...F_NAME..C_ROOM...SEMESTER
INSS300...M5:30....DWIGHT..219BC....FALL11
INSS300...T5:30....KEEN....216BC....FALL11
MKT300....M5:30....Lee.....112BC....SP11
MKT300....W5:30....Lee.....112BC....SP11
INSS421...T5:30....CORY....212BC....FALL11
FIN300....TH5:30...KEEN....219BC....FALL11
INSS300...W5:30....CORY....219BC....FALL11
INSS300...F5:30....CORY....216BC....FALL11
INSS422...F5:30....KEEN....219BC....FALL11
```

and this is sample data in the `grade` table

```
S_NAME   C_NAME     G
LARRY....INSS300....B
LARRY....FIN300.....A
SONY.....INSS300....C
SONY.....INSS421....C
GRAY.....INSS300....C
GRAY.....INSS421....D
TRUDY....INSS300....B
DRUM.....INSS421....A
DRUM.....FIN300.....B
PURI.....INSS422....C
APPLE....INSS422....C
LARRY....INSS422....C
LARRY....INSS300....B
SONY.....INSS300....C
GRAY.....INSS300....C
TRUDY....INSS300....B
```

My question that I have to answer is:

> Assume these tables are in your account Ordb002. You need to give read
>   only permission on  all three tables to your group member Sally whose
>   account is Ordb009. Assuming you have given Sally read permission on
>   all tables. Sally wants to get a count of grades (i.e., A, B, c etc..)
>   by faculty and course. Write a query for SALLY to get this count.

I have come up with this query

```
select cla.f_name
     , gra.c_name
     , count(grade)
     , grade
from class1 cla 
   , grade1 gra
where cla.c_name=gra.c_name
group by cla.f_name
       , gra.c_name
       , grade
order by cla.f_name
       , gra.c_name;
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
F_NAME               C_NAME     COUNT(GRADE) G
-------------------- ---------- ------------ -
CORY                 INSS300               4 B
CORY                 INSS300               4 C
CORY                 INSS421               1 A
CORY                 INSS421               1 C
CORY                 INSS421               1 D
DWIGHT               INSS300               2 B
DWIGHT               INSS300               2 C
KEEN                 FIN300                1 A
KEEN                 FIN300                1 B
KEEN                 INSS300               2 B
KEEN                 INSS300               2 C
KEEN                 INSS422               3 C
```

I don't know why the 4b and 4 c are coming up at the top of the output when the possibility can only be 2b and 2 c.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your class table you have "duplicate" rows for c_name and f_name, e.g.:

```
C_NAME    C_TIME   F_NAME  C_ROOM  SEMESTER
--------- -------- ------- ------- --------  
INSS300   W5:30    CORY    219BC   FALL11
INSS300   F5:30    CORY    216BC   FALL11
```

Each row in the grade table for INSS300 is going to match against those rows, resulting in double the count.

So, if your grade table doesn't also note which time the class was, you're going to have to filter your class table to only display one row per c_name and f_name.

Alternatively, you could group the rows in the grade table first, and then join them back to the class table, if you still needed to display both rows (although I don't think this would be the right approach for the problem you're trying to solve).